# Can I declare objects of many non-main class into a file other than the main executable Java file? If so, how: can it be a class, etc.?

Tags: java, class, oop, object, external

For example:
I have file 1 with the main, and Classes Class1, Class2, Class3

```java
public class Foo{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Class1 data = new Class1();
        Class1 data2 = new Class1();
        Class2 data3 = new Class2();
        Class3 data4 = new Class3();
        code...;
}
```

Is it possible that the many declarations of objects in the previous code can be moved to another file (I would say, "instances" or "objects" file) such that the output is 2 files?:

**File 1:**

```java
public class Foo{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        //Snippet for "importing" the objects in File 2, suppose import instances;
        code...;
}
```

**File 2** (at least what I would think of the file format):

```
public objects instanceFile
        Class1 data = new Class1();
        Class1 data2 = new Class1();
        Class2 data3 = new Class2();
        Class3 data4 = new Class3();
```

Comment: No, not in that way. but you could put `data ... data4` in another container class K (e.g. `public final Class1 data;`), and create an object k of class K once in Foo and access the initial stuff via `k.data1` , `k.data4`;

Comment: A java file can contain only class definitions not object definitions (unlike Scala and kotlin). You may create another class  as a composition of these classes. but still you can only import static objects (which are usually constants).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only import static objects. An example from jdk is the pi constant in the [java.lang.Math](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#PI) class.

```
   import static java.lang.Math.*;
   // or
   import static java.lang.Math.PI;
```

More details about [static import](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/static-import.html)